# NSPredicate is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to create NSPredicate Object . I have given my code below. Why do i get nil always? Is there any alternative way to do it?

```
NSString *name=@"Deva";
NSString *predicateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name contains[c] '%@'",name];
NSPredicate *namepredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];`
```

Comment: What is the value you're comparing it against? If "Deva" isn't in the data you're matching against, it'll be nil.

Comment: Why are you building your predicate this way? What if name were "O'Shaughnessy"?   NSPredicate takes a format: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", name]`

Comment: Also, I just tried and `namepredicate != nil`.  What problem are you running into?

Comment: Remove the single quotes.

Comment: Apparently he wants to build his own SQL injection. And being curious, I tried and [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat... ] will do exactly the right thing in situations like the "O'Shaughnessy" name and handle them without any problem.

Comment: @quellish it's not about the single quotes - it's about the predicate structure - pay attention to the "name" at the beginning of the predicate - it doesn't refer to anything

Comment: I am trying to filter the Array of Dictionaries which contains name = "Deva" . This code works if it is outside delegate implementation methods. It does not work if the same code into UISearchBarDeleagte methods.

Comment: @GalMarom the structure is fine. The single quotes could cause a problem and they are not needed at all. Did you actually run his problem code? The predicate is created just fine.

Comment: @DevaPalanisamy your question seems to indicate that your NSPredicate is nil. That does not seem to be the case, and does not seem to describe your actual problem. Please update your question or create a new one if your problem is the *filtering* rather than the predicate returned by `predicateWithFormat:` being nil.

Comment: The structure didnt't work for me. i The predicate is not nil but throw an exemption once you filter with it in the following way:
  NSArray *a = @[@"1",@"2",@"Deva3",@"Deva4"];
    NSString *name=@"Deva";
    NSString *predicateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@",name];
    NSPredicate *namepredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
    a = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namepredicate];

Comment: In my answer I've also took off the single quotes. 
@DevaPalanisamy - did you manage to solve it? please confirm the answer if you did

Comment: Single quotes with in predicate string is not an issue.I was able to resolve this issue by converting NSPredicate from local variable to Instance Variable.Since I am not sure how this change resolved my issue , I did not post my answer below. Local NSPredicate variable works fine in many part of my code. But some instances it works when i keep NSPredicate as instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the format of the predicate.
When you use a predicate the first variable (in your case 'name') is the property you get from the object. In String you don't have a property name.
Try:

```
    NSString *name = @"Deva";
    NSPredicate *namepredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self contains[c] %@)",name];
    arr = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namepredicate];
```